# Larger cursor in Java

Tags: java, swing, cursor, awt

Is there a possibility to create a larger cursor (by the method `createCustomCursor()`) than the  predefined 32x32 in Windows (e.g. 64x64 or even more)?

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
final Image cursor = toolkit.getImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/cursor.png"));
toolkit.getBestCursorSize(64, 64);
Cursor mycursor=toolkit.createCustomCursor(cursor, new Point(0,0), "cursor");
setCursor(mycursor);
```

I tried the following:

```
 Cursor emptyCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB), new Point(0, 0), "empty"); 
        setCursor(emptyCursor);

        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener(){
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                xCursor = e.getX();
                yCursor = e.getY();
                repaint();
                //e.consume();
            }
        });

 public void paint( Graphics g ) {
           g.drawImage(cursor, xCursor, yCursor, null);
       }
```

But it doesn't work, the whole GUI disappears, and the cursor is drawn at every point so i have to delete it in a way?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: actually the code above creates a cursor with the following size 32x32 using windows.. i would like to know, if there exist a more efficient way to program a much larger cursor!?

Comment: solved 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475404/java-does-a-mousemoved-event-and-a-button-addmouselistener-interfere

Answer (score 1):

Is there a method to make a cursor smaller than the predefined 32x32? If so just make a cursor so tiny that it really can't be noticed, or make a transparent cursor... THEN, just move an image to the coordinates of the cursors current location every (insert desired time interval here)

Answer (score 1):

Windows seem to only allow cursors of size 32x32 pixels so if you want another size you have to work around it.

To make a larger cursor I believe this will work:

- Create a custom cursor that is completely transparent.
- Use a `mouseMotionListener` to get the position of the cursor.
- Draw your cursor image at the position of the real (transparent) cursor.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to program it? because drawing the image every time the mouse is moved is inefficient!

Comment: This simplified version seems to work for me (creates an invisible cursor): `Cursor emptyCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB), new Point(0, 0), "empty"); frame.setCursor(emptyCursor);`

Comment: that wasn't the problem.. in my example i used the image cursorBlank to do this.. but the problem i probably have is in the addMouseMotionListener()..

Comment: You have to hide the cursor before you draw a new custom cursor.