# Java: does a mouseMoved event and a button.addMouseListener interfere?

Tags: java, events, cursor

Now I am using the following code to draw a cursor (with a greater size):

```
Cursor emptyCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(new BufferedImage(12, 12, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB), new Point(0, 0), "empty"); 
        setCursor(emptyCursor);

        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

        final long eventMask = AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK + AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK + AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK;
        final ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/cursor.png");
        cursorLabel = new JLabel(icon);

        toolkit.addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e) {
                MouseEvent  me=(MouseEvent)e;
                cursorLabel.setLocation(me.getLocationOnScreen().x, me.getLocationOnScreen().y);
            }
        }, eventMask);

        layeredPane = this.getLayeredPane();  
        if (icon != null) {
            cursorLabel.setBounds(15, 225, icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
        } else {
            System.err.println("Cursor Icon not found!");
        }
        layeredPane.add(cursorLabel);
```

Afterwards I used the following code for the button:

```
button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                }
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    button.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                }
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    button.setBackground(Color.white);
                }
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                }
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                } 
            });
```

The cursor works fine, but only if I don't press the button, because than it's drawn under the button.. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons have their own MouseListener to handle rollover effects. So the MouseEvent is only passed to the button and not the layered pane.

Maybe you can use an AWTEventListener to listen for your mouse events. See [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) for more information.

Comment: thank you very much. I adapted the code (see my question), but I have a small problem: when I press a button, than the mouse is drawn under the button? why?

Comment: Maybe use a Glass Pane for painting the cursor. In any case we can't help unless you post a `SSCCE` demonstrating the problem.